# Format text in Outlook mail in bold and all caps

Tags: html, css, vba, excel

I am taking values from Excel in a Do While loop, and each value is pasted in an Outlook mail every time the loop runs. I want to put that value in Outlook in **BOLD** font and also in CAPS.

```
Do until k = row_cnt 
    val1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k).Value
    Set myApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myItem = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)     
    With myItem
        .Subject = subj
        .To = email_add
        .HTMLBody = "Hello " & val1 & "Thanks"
        .Display
        '.send
    End With
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it **bold** and UPPER CASE:

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello <b>" & UCase$(val1) & "</b> Thanks"
```

you could also use a stronger inline style

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello <span style='font-weight:bold !important;'>" & UCase$(val1) & "</span> Thanks"
```

or if you wanted to do it all with an inline style:

```
.HTMLBody = "Hello <span style='font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;'>" & val1 & "</span> Thanks"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but it is not making the value BOLD.

Comment: Then you must have something overriding it.

Comment: Sorry. Its working fine. I made a mistake while copying it in my code. Thanks. :)